# Transfer contacts that are enabled for a partner portal to another account

Tags: community

I have created a community. Now I have a functionallity where community user (i.e. Contact) need to change the account.

On my search I have reffered https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=contacts_change_account_for_portals.htm&language=en_US
But in the above link I am not understanding how this can be done.
Is it possible? If yes how?

Thanks,
In advance

Comment: What issues are facing while changing accounts? You can just directly select the account lookup and update with a new account.

Comment: Issue 
1. I am using community user license. In community I am selecting a default account whose owner is system admin. 
2. So while changing the contact we are getting error.

Comment: Run the code in "Without Sharing" mode. As it will run in System mode, it won't throw any error.